# npm sets the wrong {prefix} on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I'm running node.js and npm on Windows 7.  For some bizarre reason, when I start a node.js command prompt and type `npm config ls -l`, I can see that npm has generated my {prefix} incorrectly, yet some settings point to my correct actual username.  For example, I have:

```
globalconfig = "C:\\Users\\[incorrectUsername]\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\etc\\npmrc"
userconfig = "C:\\Users\\[correctUsername]\\.npmrc"
```

How on Earth is npm generating {prefix} which is giving me an incorrect username (it looks like something I may have specified at some point as a nickname)?  It certainly isn't the username of any existing user on the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK after much searching I figured it out, sort of.

Somehow, the incorrect username had been hardcoded into the following file:

```
C:\Users\[correctUsername]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\npmrc
```

I have no idea why, but that file contained:

```
prefix=C:\Users\[incorrectUsername]\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

A bunch of stuff had been installed into the wrong place so I decided to just uninstall Node.js and start from scratch, sadly.

Comment: This happened to me after renaming a user account.